# Import data in a csv file that is structured as list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, csv

I'm trying to import data into a pandas dataframe. The file type is 'csv' but the data in the file is structured as a python list. The below code is only returning the column headers. Any suggestions? What am I doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd

data_path = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\john_smith\file_name.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data_path, columns=["article_id","author_id","viewer_id","view_date"])
df
```

An example of the data in the file is below. There aren't any headers in the file.

```
[[126,17,62,"2019-07-02"],[149,42,22,"2019-06-23"],[138,39,33,"2019-07-26"]]
```

Example of what is returned is below:

[The returned output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFv8y.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really not clear, but if you have a file that literally looks like:

`file.csv`

```
[[126,17,62,"2019-07-02"],[149,42,22,"2019-06-23"],[138,39,33,"2019-07-26"]]
```

We can attempt to read that with `ast.literal_eval`

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open('file.csv') as f:
    data = literal_eval(f.read())

print(data)
print(type(data))

# Output:

[[126, 17, 62, '2019-07-02'], [149, 42, 22, '2019-06-23'], [138, 39, 33, '2019-07-26']]
<class 'list'>
```

Now we can work with pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["article_id","author_id","viewer_id","view_date"])
print(df)

# Output:

   article_id  author_id  viewer_id   view_date
0         126         17         62  2019-07-02
1         149         42         22  2019-06-23
2         138         39         33  2019-07-26
```

Comment: Thank you @BerT2me this code worked and very simplistic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
import pandas as pd

path_file = r'C:\Users\john_smith\file_name.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(path_file, delimiter=';', names=['data'])
df['data'] = df['data'][0][1:-1]
df = df.assign(**{'data':df['data'].str.split('\],\[')})
out = df.explode('data').replace({'\[': '', '\]': '', '"': ''}, regex=True)

out = (out['data'].str.split(',', expand=True)
                  .rename(columns={0:'article_id', 1:'author_id', 2:'viewer_id', 3:'view_date'})
                  .reset_index(drop=True)
      )
```

#### `>>> print(out)`

[image]

Comment: Thank you @L'Artiste this code worked beautiful.